# Image shows up in editor, but not in published blog post

Tags: images, gallery

I'm having a problem with my blog page. I'm adding images to my blog posts and I can see them on my back-end however, not in the published blog post. Am I doing something wrong?

example page is: https://everywherehotspots.com/must-visit-coffee-shops-in-madrid/

Thank you so much.

[image: EDITOR]

[image]

Comment: Your gallery block appears empty. Have you done anything with custom code to try and customise the output of the gallery? If not, this is probably an issue better suited to the WordPress support forums: https://wordpress.org/support/view/no-replies/

Comment: confirmed, the image tags are simply not present in the raw HTML, it isn't being removed by JS, and it's not that the images don't load (they're simply not present, empty galleries!). Have you disabled all plugins to test if a plugin is the culprit? Have you made changes or added code that modifies/enhances/changes image blocks or gallery blocks? Does this happen on other themes? Has this always been the case?